# ko.mapping.fromJS adds extra subscriptions

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-mapping-plugin, kendo-window, knockout-subscribe

I'm using KO to bind data in Kendo Window. This is a sample how my html looks like

```
<form id="formid">
   <span id="window">
     <span data-bind:"html:content"></span>
   </span>
</form>
```

formId is binded with viewModel. And when document is ready I'm getting window content (html with viewModel to this window) via ajax. I do it like bellow:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(newObj, {}, viewModel);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, element);
```

newObj - is JSON object with information about fe. names of buttons etc
In newObj there are other properties. I saw that after executing `ko.mapping.fromJS`some properties has `getSubscriptionsCount()==1`. And when I try to change those properies, my window is rendering once more. document ready is triggered once again

Why I get in some properties already with subscribers after ko.mapping.fromJS and some without it? Or maybe this is a problem with kendo window

Comment: Can you show your document.ready function?

Comment: in document.ready in form I have 
`ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.getElementById('formId));` and ajax request to get content to viewModel and in success
`viewModel.content(data)`

Comment: I saw that when you touch observable property in object f.e viewModel.Name() KO automaticly add's subscriber so I think this is not a problem but problem is why kendo window tries to rerender content when was some change in viewModel of kendowindow. This is happening as well when I execute (on some property) method valueHasMutated.

Comment: adding the subscriber is also not happening with all properties.

Comment: I've changed this, and now I'm loading content via jquery not by KO. And it works.